# Using SED to replace capture group with regex pattern

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need some help with a sed command that I thought would help solve an issue I have.  I have basically have long text files that look something like this:

```
>TRINITY_DN112253_co_g1_i2 Len=3873 path=[38000:0-183]
ACTCACGCCCACATAAT
```

The ACT text blocks continue on, and then there are more blocks of text that follow the same pattern, except the text after the > differs slightly by numbers.  I want to replace only this header part (the part followed by the >) to everything up until the very last “_” the sed command I thought seemed logical is the following:

```
sed -i ‘s/>.*/TRINITY.*_/‘
```

However, sed is literally changing each header to TRINITY.*_ rather than capturing the block I thought it would.  Any help is appreciated!

(Also.. just to make things clear, I thought that my sed command would convert the top header block into this:

```
>TRINITY_DN112253_co_g1_
ACTCACGCCCACATAAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
sed '/^>/s/[^_]*$//' file
```

Output:

```
>TRINITY_DN112253_co_g1_
ACTCACGCCCACATAAT
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Appreciate this.  And although it does edit the headers, it seems to completely strip any of the text that follows the header:  (my output file looks like this now:

Comment: Good catch. I've updated my answer. The `s///` command is now only applied to lines beginning with `>`.

Comment: How about `sed '/^>/s/_[^_]*$//'` to get rid of the trailing `'_'`? (unclear what the description wants)